# How do I make arrays of my discord bot be different for different servers?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So my discord bot has an array and objects in the form of string can be pushed into that array by a discord command that I made, this array is then exported to another event file which checks if any of these words in the array are there in a message.

But I ran into a problem where if I add a word lets say "a" from server 1 and then word "b" from server 2 both the words a and b are then checked for every single server the bot is in which is definitely not what I wanted.

I tried using maps() but unfortunately for some reason I am unable to run methods on the exported maps.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Are you able to create an object that maps each array to a server?

Comment: Yes i tried doing that with maps() but was not able to run methods on them after exporting so that means after I exported them to the event file I was not able to get the values for a specific key @Ashley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely consider switching to a database!
The easiest and quickest possible database for beginners is **[quick.db](https://quickdb.js.org)**, you may then set your words freely per guild.

Here is an example:

```js
const obj_struct = {
  val: {
    word: `foo`
  }
};
db.push(`words_${message.guild.id}`, obj_struct); // it is now stored for that specific guild, now you may fetch and check it like so:
const x = client.db.get(`words_${message.guild.id}`); // does not return a promise so no need of async / await / .then() refer docs, will only get values stored for your specific guild!
```

Comment: Hey so using this can I have an entire array of multiple words for a guild.id as key that a user adds using a command and how will i be able to fetch the array for that key then?

Comment: @Zenxya forget arrays, this is a **database**. Check out the documentation linked in the answer.

Comment: Yes Zenxya! You may store an array of words within the object and push to it if required! I recommend you reading the documentation linked within so you can have a better understanding of what you're doing :)

Comment: @Zero this is misleading, Zenxya seems to think quick.db is an array of sorts, and it simply isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping each array to a server ID

So instead of your array looking like this:

```js
[ 'a', 'b']
```

It will look like

```js
{
  "Server1": ['a'],
  "Server2": ['b']
}
```

And when you edit or read from the array, only get the one mapped to the server the message is coming from.

Comment: Although this is right, it is inefficient code for a bot. Json is also notoriously bad for holding data for extended periods, and likes to wipe files occasionally.